# Set State using Void Callback flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am testing some functionality in my app where when I press a specific button(Shown in the bottom right corner) a status menu will change(Shown top center). The status menu should change to the color of the button.

I need to be able to set the state of the status menu where when I press the button it changes to the same color.

So when you press the number 2 button it will update and set the state in status_menu.dart and change the color to red.

I can change the color if I hot restart but it does not seem to change automatically. I have been able to use void callbacks in the past to fix this issue, but I am not sure how to implement them here.

If there is an easier way to accomplish this, please let me know, this is just my logic so far.

UPDATE: I was able to simplify the code so it is easier to understand, hopefully this helps.

---

What should happen when I press number 4

[image]

What should happen when I press number 2

[image]

status_menu.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hermes/menus/status_menu_functions.dart';


class StatusMenu extends StatefulWidget {

 final VoidCallback isTestButtonPressed;
 StatusMenu({required this.isTestButtonPressed});

  @override
  State<StatusMenu> createState() => _StatusMenuState();
}

class _StatusMenuState extends State<StatusMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 400.0),
          child: Image.asset(changeHeadColor()), //Head Change menu
        ),
        Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.4,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 515, top: 12.0),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/main_menu/change_heads.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/change_heads');
                }
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 600.0, left: 800),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              TestButton1(),
              TestButton2(),
              TestButton3(),
              TestButton4(),
              TestButton5(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class TestButton1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test1.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          isGreen = true;
          isRed = false;
          isBlue = false;
          isOrange = false;
          isPurple = false;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test2.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          isGreen = false;
          isRed = true;
          isBlue = false;
          isOrange = false;
          isPurple = false;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton3 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test3.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          isGreen = false;
          isRed = false;
          isBlue = true;
          isOrange = false;
          isPurple = false;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton4 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test4.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          isGreen = false;
          isRed = false;
          isBlue = false;
          isOrange = true;
          isPurple = false;
          print('Green is $isGreen');
          print('Red is $isRed');
          print('Blue is $isBlue');
          print('Orange is $isOrange');
          print('Purple is $isPurple');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton5 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test5.png'),
        onPressed: () {
          isGreen = false;
          isRed = false;
          isBlue = false;
          isOrange = false;
          isPurple = true;
          print('Green is $isGreen');
          print('Red is $isRed');
          print('Blue is $isBlue');
          print('Orange is $isOrange');
          print('Purple is $isPurple');
        },
    ),
    );
    }
  }
```

status_menu_functions.dart (Passes a string value to status_menu.dart)

```
bool isGreen = false;
bool isRed = false;
bool isBlue = false;
bool isOrange = false;
bool isPurple = false;

bool isVisible = true;

String changeHeadColor() {
  if (isGreen == true) {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_green.png';
  } else if (isRed == true) {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_red.png';
  } else if (isBlue == true) {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_blue.png';
  } else if (isOrange == true) {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_orange.png';
  } else if (isPurple == true) {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_purple.png';
  } else {
    return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_green.png';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem, I added a void callback to each textbutton class and then called setState in my build function where I called each button. That seemed to the trick, I posted the code below.

Updated status_menu.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hermes/menus/status_menu_functions.dart';


class StatusMenu extends StatefulWidget {

 final VoidCallback isTestButtonPressed;
 StatusMenu({required this.isTestButtonPressed});

  @override
  State<StatusMenu> createState() => _StatusMenuState();
}

class _StatusMenuState extends State<StatusMenu> {

  String changeHeadColor() {
    if (isGreen == true) {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_green.png';
    } else if (isRed == true) {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_red.png';
    } else if (isBlue == true) {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_blue.png';
    } else if (isOrange == true) {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_orange.png';
    } else if (isPurple == true) {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_purple.png';
    } else {
      return 'assets/main_menu/head_size_panel_green.png';
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 435.0),
          child: Image.asset(changeHeadColor()), //Head Change menu
        ),
        Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.4,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 542, top: 12.0),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Image.asset('assets/main_menu/change_heads.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/change_heads');
                }
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 600.0, left: 800),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              TestButton1(isButtonPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isGreen = true;
                  isRed = false;
                  isBlue = false;
                  isOrange = false;
                  isPurple = false;
                });
              },),
              TestButton2(isButtonPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isGreen = false;
                  isRed = true;
                  isBlue = false;
                  isOrange = false;
                  isPurple = false;
                });
              },),
              TestButton3(isButtonPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isGreen = false;
                  isRed = false;
                  isBlue = true;
                  isOrange = false;
                  isPurple = false;
                });
              },),
              TestButton4(isButtonPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isGreen = false;
                  isRed = false;
                  isBlue = false;
                  isOrange = true;
                  isPurple = false;
                });
              },),
              TestButton5(isButtonPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isGreen = false;
                  isRed = false;
                  isBlue = false;
                  isOrange = false;
                  isPurple = true;
                });
              },),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class TestButton1 extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback isButtonPressed;
  TestButton1({required this.isButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test1.png'),
        onPressed: isButtonPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton2 extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback isButtonPressed;
  TestButton2({required this.isButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test2.png'),
        onPressed: isButtonPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton3 extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback isButtonPressed;
  TestButton3({required this.isButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test3.png'),
        onPressed: isButtonPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton4 extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback isButtonPressed;
  TestButton4({required this.isButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test4.png'),
        onPressed: isButtonPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestButton5 extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback isButtonPressed;
  TestButton5({required this.isButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.4,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/change_heads/test5.png'),
        onPressed: isButtonPressed,
    ),
    );
    }
  }
```